# How to improve automatic MySQL Database Backup command (For linux users)

Tags: mysql, linux, command, backup

Am quite new in server management. Now am struggling to restore one database from whole MySql backup. Currently i have a mysql backup. Am using the following command for backup.

```
Mysqldump –u root –password={actual password for mysql} –h localhost –all-databases > /backup/mysql_backup.sql
gzip -9 /backup/mysql_backup.sql
```

I would like to improve this backup, because each back file should be more than 2.5 Gb and restoring is very difficult. If i can't restore from it, then what is the purpose of this backup? So i would like to improve this. Suppose i want to restore a particular database, then its very tedious to find that from this 3Gb file . So i would like to backup each database in a separate file. Any suggestion to improve the above command??

Comment: I suggest you backup your databases separately if you are worried about size.

Comment: Any suggestion for improving the above command??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)